# Concatenation of int array and char array in C

Tags: c

Example

```
int a[2] = {1,2};
char b[5] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' };
```

Is that possible to combine two arrays and create a 2D array and get a result:

```
1A 1B 1C 1D
2A 2B 2C 2D
```

I tried to create a 2D array like:

```
char c[2][4]={{'1A','1B','1C','1D'},{'2A','2B','2C','2D'}}
```

but it giving me error.

Comment: `'1A'` --> `0x1A`

Comment: A string cannot be surrounded by the single quote; it must be surrounded by double quotes. So you don't have an array of `char` but of `char *`.

Comment: Not clear what you want. You ask about concatenating arrays, but then show an example of combining the elements. First you should try to understand the problem, elaborate a solution and **then** implement it.

Comment: The single quote makes it a character but you show two characters in the initialization. Do you mean a string (double quotes) in the character array? "1A", "1B", ...

Answer (score 0):

'1A' is not syntactically correct. Single quotes are used to represent character literals and can only enclose one character.

Here's a sketch of something that might work, if you want to combine a and b into an array of pairs at runtime:

```
int a[2] = {1,2};
char b[5] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' };
char *pairs[2][5];

for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    pairs[i][j] = (char*)malloc(2 * sizeof(char));
    sprintf(pairs[i][j], "%d%c", a[i], b[j]);
}
```

If you just want to initialize an array of pairs this should work:

```
 char* pairs[2][5] = {{"1A", "1B", "1C", "1D"}, {"2A", "2B", "2C", "2D"}};
```